# JavaFx hide TextArea-VScrollbar

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

looking up this question I found this snippet:

> Remove Vertical Scrollbar

```
ScrollBar scrollBarv = (ScrollBar)ta.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
scrollBarv.setDisable(true);
```

> CSS

```
.text-area .scroll-bar:vertical:disabled {
-fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

But this dont works for me.
I created a minimal example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

        root.setCenter(textArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("Style.css");

        ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) textArea.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
        System.out.println(scrollBar);
        scrollBar.setDisable(true);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.text-area .scroll-bar:vertical:disabled {
-fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

But all I get is a Nullpointer-Exception.

```
Exception in Application start method
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at    com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main.start(Main.java:33)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
... 1 more
```

So what are Im doing wrong or is there another solution?

Comment: can you show us the Stacktrace you're getting?

Comment: @Flika205 I added it

Comment: Seems like you're getting an error on this line: `scrollBar.setDisable(true);`. because your scrollBar isn't initialized, check [scrollBar API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/scrollbar.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was that lookup() dont works until the scene is rendered. Changing the sequence worked.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

    root.setCenter(textArea);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("Style.css");

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();

    ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) textArea.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
    System.out.println(scrollBar);
    scrollBar.setDisable(true);
}
```